# HTTP triggers for Postgres

Tags: http, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to write a Postgres trigger such that when a configuration table is updated, a backend component is notified and can handle the change. I know that Oracle has the concept of a web/HTTP trigger, where you can execute an HTTP GET from the Oracle instance itself to a URL that can then handle the request at the application layer. I'm wondering if Postgres (`v. 9.0.5`) has the same feature, or comes with anything similar (and, subsequently, how to set it up/configure it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call a Python stored procedure with [PL/Python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpython-funcs.html) from your trigger and make your http get request using Python's standard libraries.